# Nonlinear Diffusion Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Suppose that $u(x, t)$ be a solution to the nonlinear diffusion equation
$$u_{t} = \frac{1}{2}u_{xx}+u^2 \textrm{ for   }  0<x<\pi \textrm{ and}$$
$$u(0,t) = u(\pi,t) = 0$$
Prove that $u(x, t)$ cannot be finite (what does this mean?) at $t = ln(\frac{c_0}{c_0−1})$, provided the initial data is sufficiently large at places in the domain:
$$\int_{0}^{\pi} u(x,0)\sin(x)dx = c_{0} >1$$
Hint: Use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality

I'm unsure how to apply the inequality nor how that would even help in a problem like this

Comment: You should clarify a problem you have by editing. Do you have a difficulty in finding how to apply the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality in this case, or in interpreting consequences of the inequality?

Answer (score 0):

Further hint:

$$ \dfrac{d}{dt} \int_0^\pi u(x,t)\; \sin(x)\; dx 
 = \dfrac{1}{2} \int_0^\pi u_{xx}(x,t) \; \sin(x)\; dx + \int_0^\pi u(x,t)^2\; \sin(x)\; dx$$
Integrate the first term by parts twice, and use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to relate the second term to $\int_0^\pi u(x,t) \sin(t)\; dt$.

Comment: how do you integrate function $u(x,t)$ without knowing what $u(x,t)$ is ?

Comment: Where did I say you do that?  The results of these integrations by parts are integrals that still involve $u(x,t)$.

Comment: "Integrate the first term by parts twice"

Comment: Yes, and as I said, you should get an integral that involves $u(x,t)$.

Comment: First term on the right hand-side is what is meant, namely $$\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\pi u_{xx}\sin(x) dx $$